# javascript toISOString() acts different in firefox and chrome

Tags: javascript, date

```
var d = new Date("2016-07-28T11:19:50.167");
var n = d.toISOString();
```

If in firefox, the result is `"2016-07-28T17:19:50.167Z"`, but chrome doesn't work only if change input to `"2016-07-28 11:19:50.167 PST"`, and the result is also different `"2016-07-28T18:19:50.167Z"`, anybody know this?

Comment: "but chrome doesn't work" --- it surely *works* here.

Comment: the difference in output seems to be a summertime difference? as far as parsing input, yeah, thank you big three browsers for only having one common text format for date, that is probably the least useful

Comment: actually, without the Z suffix, firefox treats `2016-07-28T11:19:50.167` as local time, whereas chrome treats it as UTC

Comment: Yet again, parsing of strings using the Date constructor fails. Just don't to it, ever. **Always** manually parse the string. Use a library, write a small function, whatever, but **do not use the Date constructor** (or Date.parse, they are equivalent for parsing).

Comment: I've marked this as a duplicate because the issue isn't with *toISOString*, it's with parsing using the Date constructor. The duplicate answer shows why that's a bad idea.